# matching values in router events ternary statement

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object

```
pages = {
    url1: 'page1',
    url2: 'page2',
    url3: 'page3',
    url4: 'page4',
    url5: 'page5',
    url6: 'page6'
  }
```

I have a function that gets the page URL from the router

Within the function, I use object.keys to iterate over the object values, if one of the values matches it should set other variables.

I want to use a ternary statement but could someone tell me why it doesn't work?

A normal if statement does...

```
 private pages(): void {
    this.subs = this.router.events
      .pipe(
          filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      )
      .subscribe((event) => {

       let index: number;
       let found: boolean;

       Object.keys(this.progressUrls).map((key, i) => {

          if (this.progressUrls[key]  === event['url']){
 // This works
            found = true;
              more stuff....
          }

// The below does not work
   event['url'] === this.progressUrls[key] ? (found = true, index = i) : (found = false, index = 0)

            });

         });
      }
```

Comment: if you change your working `if` to below, do you still get expected result
 `if (this.progressUrls[key]  === event['url']) { found = true;} else { found = false;}`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to understand why the ternary statement isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two code are not same

- In your normal `if`, you set the value of `found` to `true` when you condition is `true`, and there is no `else` statement. it means once it's set to true it will stay true until the end of loop, and no code is setting it to `false`
- In your ternary, on each loop you set value of `found` to `true` or `false` and means when your loop is ended, value is result of the last item in the loop

So these code are different in logic
If you add `else` statement to the `if` and set `found = false` then logic of the code and result will be same (although it might not be your expected result)

If you need to have same logic as your simple if in ternary way use the below

```
 event['url'] === this.progressUrls[key] ? (found = true, index = i) : (index = 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, using the ternary statement meant the values never seemed to be right, for the reason you gave above, when I used the if else and returned the result it worked!! Do you know a more compact way of doing this?

Comment: @Rasta just remember readability is more important than a compact code